# Not able to run standalone application with spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javafx

Case 1: When `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` is used, i could run the application through netbeans IDE but if i create a deployable jar it, file not found exception is thrown

Case 2: when `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is used, i couldnt run the appplication thorugh IDE or even thorough deployable jar it throws,  `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Utils class to access Spring Config:

```
 package com.pts.utils;

 import com.pts.action.login.LoginController;
 import com.pts.dto.login.LoginDto;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

 /**
  *
  * @author rpashank
   */
  public class Utils {

   private static Utils fxUtils;

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static Utils getInstance() {
     if (fxUtils == null) {
        fxUtils = new Utils();
    }
    return fxUtils;
}

private Utils() {

      }

  public Object getBean(String beanName) {


  //        ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/resources/spring-config.xml");


          ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/src/main/resources/spring-config.xml");


       Object bean = ctx.getBean(beanName);


       return bean;

  }
  }
```

Spring Configuration File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><beans           xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

   <bean   id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PMA2014"></property>
     <property name="username" value="root"></property>
     <property name="password" value="root"></property>
  </bean>


    <bean   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   </bean>

    <bean   class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate" name="transactionTemplate">
       <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>


   <bean   autowire="byName" class="com.pts.service.login.LoginServiceImpl" id="loginService" name="loginService"/>
   <bean   class="com.pts.dao.login.LoginDaoImpl" id="loginDao">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get. I have a wild hunch that you have forgotten to put a jar on the classpath.

Comment: remove `src/main/resources` from the path that basically is the root of your classpath. So use `classpath:spring-config.xml`.

Comment: @Juru : For FileSystemXmlApplicationContext the error is Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\spring-config.xml (
The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSys
temResource.java:113)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
        ... 68 more

Comment: @Juru for ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'loginService' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)

Comment: @Deinum if i use classpath:spring-config.xml nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Then your setup is wrong. When using maven (at least what you use is the maven path structure) the `src/main/resources` are added to the root of your class path. If that isn't the case you either haven't correctly build the project or the file isn't at the location you make us believe it is. You can try `classpath*:/spring-config.xml` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum i am also doubting correct build of the project..the file is defiantly there as if you see case 1, i am able to run but only via IDE..if i use "classpath*" then NoSuchBeanDefinitionException thrown...

Comment: If you get that exception it means the bean isn't there it does mean however that the context loaded.

Comment: @M.Deinum but if you observe the spring xml, the bean is also there, if there was issue with bean then it shouldnt run with FileSystemXmlApplicationContext through IDE..the issue is only when i deploy it.

Comment: Hence you have a problem in your setup altogether… Use maven don't try to mix the netbeans and maven support/patterns as those conflict.